# Issues with changing array defined in C++ from JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've wrote a native method in Java that uses JNI to call C++ code.

I've got JNI working fine, but when I modify an array made in C++ with JNI it only shows the modification inside the method and not outside.

Java class:

```java
package test;

public class JavaTest {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }
    
    private native void start();
    
    private native void updateArray(int index, boolean result);
    
    private void runStuff() throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> start()).start();
        
        while (true) {
            updateArray(0, true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            updateArray(0, false);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new JavaTest().runStuff();
    }
    
}
```

The while loop is calling the C++ function to change the array, which is where I can see the change inside the function body.

C++ code:

```cpp
#include "test_JavaTest.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

bool arr[3] = {false, false, false};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_JavaTest_start(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "value: " << arr[0] << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_JavaTest_updateArray(JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObject, jint index, jboolean result) {
    arr[index] = result;
    std::cout << "local value: " << arr[index] << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
value: 1
value: 1
local value: 0
local value: 1
value: 1
local value: 0
local value: 1
value: 1
local value: 0
local value: 1
value: 1
local value: 0
local value: 1
value: local value: 10
local value: 1
value: 1
local value: 0
local value: 1
value: 1
local value: 0
local value: 1
```

The "value" print statement doesn't change but the "local value" print statement does.

Comment: Made the appropriate changes. Thanks.

Comment: you need to use a mutex or atomic to ensure the changes from one thread are visible on another one. `value` is always the same as the most recent `local value`, isn't that to be expected?

Comment: You're setting the value to false and then immediately back to true without an intervening sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens in this loop:

```
    while (true) {
        updateArray(0, true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        updateArray(0, false);
    }
```

If we mentally "unroll" it, the issue becomes obvious:

```
        updateArray(0, true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        updateArray(0, false);
        updateArray(0, true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        updateArray(0, false);
        updateArray(0, true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        updateArray(0, false);
```

The other thread simply never sees the value `false` as it is immediately changed back to `true`.

If you add another `Thread.sleep(1000);` after `updateArray(0, false);`, then it should work better:

```
    while (true) {
        updateArray(0, true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        updateArray(0, false);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

However, you should use some kind of synchronization between threads. It is not guaranteed that `Sleep` or JNI calls act as a synchronization mechanism, and reading and writing memory without synchronization will invoke undefined behavior (in this specific case it will probably appear to work as intended as the compiler can't "see" past `Sleep` and will probably play it safe with optimizing array access, especially given its external linkage).